# Black screen after installing new login screen

Tags: login, kubuntu

I changed my login screen. After rebooting and choosing kubuntu as a dualboot option, kubuntu boots into a black screen in which I can see my mouse pointer.
I can't log in. Is there a way to repair this or to undo the changes I made?

EDIT: I managed to open the terminal so my question is, whether it is possible to change the login screen using the terminal.

Comment: There are several possible questions here: What display manager do you use? Which greeter do you use? Did you change a default file? Could you provide a list of what exactly you installed (packages, ideally with dependencies)?

Comment: It is completely new installation, i was just changing the themes (everything worked tho before changing the log in screen, including rebooting). I am also new to linux, so I don't know how to find these without actually getting into the linux. The only question I can answer is that I did not change a default file. Sorry for not being able to provide more info.

Comment: You stated that you were "installing new Login Screen" and "changed [your] login screen". What exactly did you click (or enter into your console) and which packages did you install, which did ones you remove? [Themes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_(computing)) are separate from your greeter, which normally is responsible for the login screen. To give a list of the installed packages relevant, you could open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal), type in `apt list *greeter* --installed` for the greeter and `apt list --installed *dm` for the display manager.

Comment: Ok, sorry fo being unclear. I simply went to setting -> Start Up and Shutdown -> Login Screen and installed&set a new one. My problem is that after booting into kubuntu, I get blackscreen and I am unable to do anything (including using terminal), I believe that I should log in but nothing is displayed. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You could try attaining the [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_(unix)) by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 after you screen blackout. That's normally a still possible way to change parts of the system when the more intutive/graphical ways are impossible. F1 should do it. If it doesn't, try the other F-keys (e. g. F2, … F12), in combination with Ctrl + Alt.

Comment: I have just tried all of these but I am affraid it doesnt work for me.

Comment: So nothing changed in the very first line (upper right corner) of the screen after trying them with a second or two in between two key presses?

Comment: When it's a completely new installation, I'd recommend re-installing it and then recording painstakingly every step, every change you do. Maybe using pen and paper here would be more proper if your system really behaves as strange like this for such simple changes.

Comment: Exactly, tried multiple times. All I see is black screen with my mouse (I can move it around).

Comment: Well I think the problem might be in this very login screen, since I tried a different one prior to that and everythink worked just fine. Thanks for those advices tho :)

Comment: Your screen **should** change its appearance, for Ctrl + Alt + F{1..12} is a more system-wide keystroke combination… Did you try Alt + Print + B? Ctrl + Alt + Del? Does anything change here? You're absolutely sure that you're *not* in a virtual machine or something comparable?

Comment: Did you try some other keystroke combinations? Which ones? DId you right/middle/left (double) click your mouse? Did you also try to get your mouse pointer out of the four screen borders? If it worked, how much space is there you can't see (estimately)?

Comment: Ok, just managed to get to the console, involved pressing Fn key along Ctr+Alt+Del. Typing `apt list *greeter* --installed` just wrote Listing done,  `apt list --installed *dm` gave me kde-config-sddm and sddm.